# access UI in onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments

I didn't find a clear statement in the doc about this but in the examples I always find that in the `onSaveInstanceState` of a fragment there is no access to the UI even just to get the state to be saved.
I see that normally the state is saved in member variable and these variables are used to save the state.

Is this a requirements?